# Programmatically disable port on WM5 device?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

Is there a way to block incoming connections on a specified port on a windows mobile 5 device, programmatically?  I am also using .NET CF 3.5.

I specifically am trying to disable PPTP (port 1723) on a windows mobile 5 pocket pc.  I have found the PPTP drivers in the registry, but would prefer a port-blocking solution to disabling any drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, port blocking is usually done by using a firewall software. Windows Mobile does not provide a firewall, so you may need to use a commercial option for this ([Airscanner](http://www.airscanner.com/products/firewall/) for example)